# About jquery treetable event handle trigger

Tags: jquery

I meet a problem when tracing jquery treetable. I didn't see any jquery bind 
function, but when I click the arrow icon, it will invoke the method, like following:

```
 $.fn.treetable = function(method) {
    if (methods[method]) {
      return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
      return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
      return $.error("Method " + method + " does not exist on jQuery.treetable");
    }
  };
```

But I didn't see any function to invoke that.
Another code snippet is from html, I see this

```
<span class="indenter" style="padding-left: 0px;"><a href="#" title="Expanding">&nbsp;</a></span>
```

I can't figure out how it work, does any one know the answer, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indeed uses jquery to bind the event.
like following:

```
target.off("click.treetable").on("click.treetable", handler);
```